# Selecting multiple checkboxes to show similar but different boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 checkbox's with 8 different combinations and outcomes.

- Selecting no checkboxes shows no divs.
- Selecting one checkbox shows the colored div.
  For example; clicking the red checkbox.
- Selecting two checkboxes shows the color1+color2 div. But doesn't show either of the single colored divs.
  For example; clicking the red and green checkboxes shows the redgreen div. But ensures both the red and green div boxes are hidden so there's only ever one div box showing.
- Selecting all the checkboxes shows the rgb div. And doesn't show any other divs.

It does work I was wondering if this can be wrote in a simpler fashion?

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    $('.box').hide();
if ($('#red').is(':checked')) $('.red.box').show();
if ($('#green').is(':checked')) $('.green.box').show();
if ($('#blue').is(':checked')) $('.blue.box').show();    
       
if ($('#red').is(':checked') && $('#green').is(':checked')) $('.redgreen.box').show() && $('.red.box, .green.box').hide();

if ($('#red').is(':checked') && $('#blue').is(':checked')) $('.redblue.box').show() && $('.red.box, .blue.box').hide();

if ($('#green').is(':checked') && $('#blue').is(':checked')) $('.greenblue.box').show() && $('.green.box, .blue.box').hide();    

if ($('#red').is(':checked') && $('#green').is(':checked') && $('#blue').is(':checked'))  $('.rgb.box').show() && $('.red.box, .green.box, .greenblue, .redblue, .redgreen.box, .blue.box').hide();    

});
```

```css
.box {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.redblue .redgreen .greenblue {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.rgb {
    border: 1px dashed black;
}
.red {
    background: #ff0000;
}
.green {
    background: #00ff00;
}
.blue {
    background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="red" name="colorCheckbox" value="red">red</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="green" name="colorCheckbox" value="green">green</label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="blue" name="colorCheckbox" value="blue">blue</label>
</div>
<div class="red box"><strong>red</strong></div>
<div class="green box"><strong>green</strong></div>
<div class="blue box"><strong>blue</strong></div>

<div class="redgreen box"><strong>red green</strong></div>
<div class="redblue box"><strong>red blue</strong></div>
<div class="greenblue box"><strong>green blue</strong></div>

<div class="rgb box"><strong>rgb</strong></div>
```

Comment: This question is lacking any explanation of what the code should _do_.  "3 checkbox's with 8 different combinations and outcomes" doesn't explain what value this has to the user.

Comment: No value for the user. But I've now explained in the OP what the outcome should be.

Comment: @Lowis I think what Toby Speight meant by value was "what problem does your code solve for a user of your code" or "how does your code implement a feature a user of your code may want". As such I think Toby is asking why you wrote the code, less what is your code doing

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on your code:

- If you don't need supporting of very old or non-standard browsers, and given that your project does not relies heavily on jQuery, vanilla JavaScript can do the same work, without jQuery's overhead.
- On each checkbox click, all coloured divs are queried again and again (`jQuery('.box')`), which is unnecessary as there are no changes in the DOM.
- All checkboxes are queried multiple times, instead of selecting them once.
- The if-then structure is quite cumbersome: *if #red is checked, show .red.box. Then, if #green is also checked, hide .red.box and show .redgreen.box. Then, if #blue is checked too, hide .redgreen.box and show .rbg.box.* One way for improving this part would be to first determine exactly which box should be checked and show only that box.
- Personally, I would have used combinations of the `.red`/`.green`/`.blue` classes, instead of putting a different class for each combination (e.g. `.box.red.green.blue` instead of `.box.rgb`). That way each checkbox corresponds with a particular div class.

Here is my take on the problem/homework/exercise, that addresses most of the above remarks (no CSS/HTML changes; still using jQuery):

```
        const RED = 1;
        const GREEN = 2;
        const BLUE = 4;

        const DIV_CLASSES_MAP = [null, '.red', '.green', '.redgreen', '.blue', '.redblue', '.greenblue', '.rgb'];
        const DIVS = $('.box');
        const RED_TICK = $('#red');
        const GREEN_TICK = $('#green');
        const BLUE_TICK = $('#blue');

        let activeDiv = DIVS.filter(':visible');
        $('input[name="colorCheckbox"]').on('click', onCheckboxChange);

        function onCheckboxChange() {
            const redBit = RED_TICK.is(':checked') ? RED : 0;
            const greenBit = GREEN_TICK.is(':checked') ? GREEN : 0;
            const blueBit = BLUE_TICK.is(':checked') ? BLUE : 0;
            const mask = redBit + greenBit + blueBit;
            const activeClass = DIV_CLASSES_MAP[mask];
            activeDiv.hide();
            activeDiv = DIVS.filter(activeClass).show();
        }
```

Comment: I don't need support for older or non-standard browsers so I'll look into a javascript alternative. Does your solution use less queries on the checkbox/s? Thank you.